# why do data sometimes split into 4 stets and sometimes into 2 (any difference)?

Tags: split, nlp, data-science

As the question explains,

working with some examples I see sometimes that when splitting the datasets its either like

```
xtrain,xtest,ytrain,ytest=train_test_split()
```

or

```
train,test= train_test_split()
```

but none of these examples explains why? is there any difference?  specially for NLP tasks.

Comment: I guess this is Python syntax? In general, you can put as many variables on the left hand side as the number of values produced by the function on the right of the `=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xtrain,xtest,ytrain,ytest=train_test_split()
```

For this one is used for supervised learning task and when you have x,y where you have a labeled dataset and are training a model to predict the target values (y) given the input features (x).

```
train,test= train_test_split()
```

This one used for unsperviosed learning where we don't have labeled data and are instead trying to find patterns in the data or cluster similar examples together.

For example, when we have document and trying to cluster data into one based on their content.

Hope that helps.

Comment: already did! .................... ;)